# How to combine integer columns to form date in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with columns salDay,SalYear and Salmonth.saLday stores intergers between 1 and 31 , salYear stores integer years e.g 2013,2015... and salMonth stores interger months between 1 and 12.I want to populate another column called received_date by combining salday,salmonth and salyear to get a date in the form of DD/MM/YYYY.

any ideas please ?

Comment: Why are you storing it split up in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You could just concatenate the columns (explicitly or implcitly converted to strings) together and use `to_date()` to convert the result to an actual date:

```
create table your_table (salDay number, salMonth number, salYear number);
insert into your_table (salDay, salMonth, salYear) values (27, 3, 2019);

select to_date(salYear ||'-'|| salMonth ||'-'|| salDay, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as salDate
from your_table;

SALDATE            
-------------------
2019-03-27 00:00:00
```

If you want this as another column in your table then you can use a virtual column with the same conversion:

```
alter table your_table
add salDate date generated always as (to_date(salYear ||'-'|| salMonth ||'-'|| salDay, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

Table YOUR_TABLE altered.

select * from your_table;

    SALDAY   SALMONTH    SALYEAR SALDATE            
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
        27          3       2019 2019-03-27 00:00:00
```

Of course, both of these will have problems if you have an invalid date. In the first case it'll error when you use that query; in the second it'll error when you query the new column. But it won't stop you putting bad data in still.

```
insert into your_table (salDay, salMonth, salYear) values (29, 2, 2019);

1 row inserted.

select * from your_table;

ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

You could use an index or constraint on that virtual column to prevent that though - anything that will cause the conversion to be attempted as part of the insert, which in turn will cause the insert to fail:

```
create index your_index on your_table (salDate);

Index YOUR_INDEX created.

insert into your_table (salDay, salMonth, salYear) values (29, 2, 2019);

ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```